# PHP_BINDIR points to a non existing directory

Tags: php, windows

I am using the command `PHP_BINDIR` to find out the location of the PHP bin directory.

```
<?php
    echo PHP_BINDIR;
```

However, I get `C:\php` even though this directory does not even exists?!
Is this a bug or why does it point to this location?